# Npm install dependencies error (pdf.js plugin)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Please help JS wizards!
On M1 Macbook Pro.
npm version 8.12.1

Package:
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

**Error on npm install**

```
[master][~/__Dev/_NewApps/pdf.js]$ npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: eslint-plugin-mozilla@2.12.3
npm ERR! Found: eslint-plugin-prettier@4.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-plugin-prettier
npm ERR!   dev eslint-plugin-prettier@"^4.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint-plugin-prettier@"^3.0.0" from eslint-plugin-mozilla@2.12.3
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-plugin-mozilla
npm ERR!   dev eslint-plugin-mozilla@"^2.12.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint-plugin-prettier@3.4.1
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-plugin-prettier
npm ERR!   peer eslint-plugin-prettier@"^3.0.0" from eslint-plugin-mozilla@2.12.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-plugin-mozilla
npm ERR!     dev eslint-plugin-mozilla@"^2.12.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /Users/mike/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mike/.npm/_logs/2022-06-29T06_18_11_165Z-debug-0.log
```

**Steps to reproduce the problem:**

```
git clone https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js.git
cd pdf.js
npm install -g gulp-cli
npm install
```

```
[master][~/__Dev/_NewApps/pdf.js]$ npm -v
8.12.1
```

I tried various updates and npm-check-updates-package to see if there is anything that needs to be updated but still got this error:

```
*[master][~/__Dev/_NewApps/pdf.js]$ npm install
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: pdf.js@undefined
npm WARN Found: eslint-plugin-prettier@4.0.0
npm WARN node_modules/eslint-plugin-prettier
npm WARN   dev eslint-plugin-prettier@"^4.1.0" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer eslint-plugin-prettier@"^3.0.0" from eslint-plugin-mozilla@2.12.3
npm WARN node_modules/eslint-plugin-mozilla
npm WARN   dev eslint-plugin-mozilla@"^2.12.3" from the root project
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: eslint-plugin-mozilla@2.12.3
npm ERR! Found: prettier@2.7.1
npm ERR! node_modules/prettier
npm ERR!   dev prettier@"^2.7.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer prettier@">=2.0.0" from stylelint-prettier@2.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/stylelint-prettier
npm ERR!     dev stylelint-prettier@"^2.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (eslint-plugin-prettier)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer prettier@"^1.19.1" from eslint-plugin-mozilla@2.12.3
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-plugin-mozilla
npm ERR!   dev eslint-plugin-mozilla@"^2.12.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: prettier@1.19.1
npm ERR! node_modules/prettier
npm ERR!   peer prettier@"^1.19.1" from eslint-plugin-mozilla@2.12.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-plugin-mozilla
npm ERR!     dev eslint-plugin-mozilla@"^2.12.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /Users/mike/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mike/.npm/_logs/2022-06-29T06_24_32_162Z-debug-0.log
```

Running on M1 Macbook Pro.

Any help?

Also npm audit fix --force gives this massive error

```
[master][~/__Dev/_NewApps/pdf.js]$ npm audit fix --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN audit fix json-schema@0.2.3 node_modules/npm/node_modules/json-schema
npm WARN audit fix json-schema@0.2.3 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix json-schema@0.2.3 npm@6.14.15 at node_modules/npm
npm WARN audit fix json-schema@0.2.3 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix json-schema@0.2.3 Check for updates to the npm package.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rc/node_modules/minimist
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 fsevents@1.2.9 at node_modules/fsevents
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/minimist
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 fsevents@1.2.9 at node_modules/fsevents
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.5 node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tar/node_modules/minimist
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.5 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.5 fsevents@1.2.9 at node_modules/fsevents
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.5 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.5 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.5 node_modules/npm/node_modules/minimist
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.5 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.5 npm@6.14.15 at node_modules/npm
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.5 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.5 Check for updates to the npm package.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.5 node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/node_modules/minimist
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.5 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.5 npm@6.14.15 at node_modules/npm
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.5 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.5 Check for updates to the npm package.
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 node_modules/npm/node_modules/string-width/node_modules/ansi-regex
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 npm@6.14.15 at node_modules/npm
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@3.0.0 Check for updates to the npm package.
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@4.1.0 node_modules/npm/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/ansi-regex
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@4.1.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@4.1.0 npm@6.14.15 at node_modules/npm
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@4.1.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@4.1.0 Check for updates to the npm package.
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@4.1.0 node_modules/npm/node_modules/wrap-ansi/node_modules/ansi-regex
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@4.1.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@4.1.0 npm@6.14.15 at node_modules/npm
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@4.1.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@4.1.0 Check for updates to the npm package.
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@4.1.0 node_modules/npm/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/ansi-regex
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@4.1.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@4.1.0 npm@6.14.15 at node_modules/npm
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@4.1.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix ansi-regex@4.1.0 Check for updates to the npm package.
npm WARN audit fix got@6.7.1 node_modules/npm/node_modules/got
npm WARN audit fix got@6.7.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix got@6.7.1 npm@6.14.15 at node_modules/npm
npm WARN audit fix got@6.7.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix got@6.7.1 Check for updates to the npm package.
npm WARN audit fix jsprim@1.4.1 node_modules/npm/node_modules/jsprim
npm WARN audit fix jsprim@1.4.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix jsprim@1.4.1 npm@6.14.15 at node_modules/npm
npm WARN audit fix jsprim@1.4.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix jsprim@1.4.1 Check for updates to the npm package.
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/mkdirp
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 fsevents@1.2.9 at node_modules/fsevents
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
npm WARN audit fix package-json@4.0.1 node_modules/npm/node_modules/package-json
npm WARN audit fix package-json@4.0.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix package-json@4.0.1 npm@6.14.15 at node_modules/npm
npm WARN audit fix package-json@4.0.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix package-json@4.0.1 Check for updates to the npm package.
npm WARN audit fix latest-version@3.1.0 node_modules/npm/node_modules/latest-version
npm WARN audit fix latest-version@3.1.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix latest-version@3.1.0 npm@6.14.15 at node_modules/npm
npm WARN audit fix latest-version@3.1.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix latest-version@3.1.0 Check for updates to the npm package.
npm WARN audit fix update-notifier@2.5.0 node_modules/npm/node_modules/update-notifier
npm WARN audit fix update-notifier@2.5.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix update-notifier@2.5.0 npm@6.14.15 at node_modules/npm
npm WARN audit fix update-notifier@2.5.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix update-notifier@2.5.0 Check for updates to the npm package.
npm WARN audit fix libnpx@10.2.4 node_modules/npm/node_modules/libnpx
npm WARN audit fix libnpx@10.2.4 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix libnpx@10.2.4 npm@6.14.15 at node_modules/npm
npm WARN audit fix libnpx@10.2.4 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix libnpx@10.2.4 Check for updates to the npm package.
npm WARN audit No fix available for wintersmith@*
npm WARN audit No fix available for jstransformer-markdown-it@*
npm WARN audit Updating vinyl-fs to 2.4.1,which is a SemVer major change.
npm WARN audit Updating gulp to 3.9.1,which is a SemVer major change.
npm WARN audit Updating gulp-zip to 4.2.0,which is a SemVer major change.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: eslint-plugin-mozilla@2.12.3
npm WARN Found: eslint-plugin-prettier@4.0.0
npm WARN node_modules/eslint-plugin-prettier
npm WARN   dev eslint-plugin-prettier@"^4.0.0" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer eslint-plugin-prettier@"^3.0.0" from eslint-plugin-mozilla@2.12.3
npm WARN node_modules/eslint-plugin-mozilla
npm WARN   dev eslint-plugin-mozilla@"^2.12.3" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: eslint-plugin-prettier@3.4.1
npm WARN node_modules/eslint-plugin-prettier
npm WARN   peer eslint-plugin-prettier@"^3.0.0" from eslint-plugin-mozilla@2.12.3
npm WARN   node_modules/eslint-plugin-mozilla
npm WARN     dev eslint-plugin-mozilla@"^2.12.3" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: eslint-plugin-mozilla@2.12.3
npm WARN Found: prettier@2.7.1
npm WARN node_modules/prettier
npm WARN   peer prettier@">=2.0.0" from eslint-plugin-prettier@4.0.0
npm WARN   node_modules/eslint-plugin-prettier
npm WARN     dev eslint-plugin-prettier@"^4.0.0" from the root project
npm WARN   2 more (stylelint-prettier, the root project)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer prettier@"^1.19.1" from eslint-plugin-mozilla@2.12.3
npm WARN node_modules/eslint-plugin-mozilla
npm WARN   dev eslint-plugin-mozilla@"^2.12.3" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: prettier@1.19.1
npm WARN node_modules/prettier
npm WARN   peer prettier@"^1.19.1" from eslint-plugin-mozilla@2.12.3
npm WARN   node_modules/eslint-plugin-mozilla
npm WARN     dev eslint-plugin-mozilla@"^2.12.3" from the root project
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.9: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated natives@1.1.6: This module relies on Node.js's internals and will break at some point. Do not use it, and update to graceful-fs@4.x.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.4: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.3.5: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.12.7: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)
npm WARN deprecated highlight.js@9.18.5: Support has ended for 9.x series. Upgrade to @latest
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.9: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/mike/Dropbox/__Documents/_Apps/_NewApps/pdf.js/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --update-binary
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/18.4.0/bin/node /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/Users/mike/Dropbox/__Documents/_Apps/_NewApps/pdf.js/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/mike/Dropbox/__Documents/_Apps/_NewApps/pdf.js/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.5
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@18.4.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.3/canvas-v2.9.3-node-v108-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.3/canvas-v2.9.3-node-v108-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.9.3 and node@18.4.0 (node-v108 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.3/canvas-v2.9.3-node-v108-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.4.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.4.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.9 found at "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/mike/Dropbox/__Documents/_Apps/_NewApps/pdf.js/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/mike/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.4.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/mike/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.4.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/mike/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.4.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/mike/Dropbox/__Documents/_Apps/_NewApps/pdf.js/node_modules/canvas',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Package pixman-1 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
npm ERR! Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pixman-1.pc'
npm ERR! to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
npm ERR! No package 'pixman-1' found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:261:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:537:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.5.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/18.4.0/bin/node" "/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary" "--module=/Users/mike/Dropbox/__Documents/_Apps/_NewApps/pdf.js/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/Users/mike/Dropbox/__Documents/_Apps/_NewApps/pdf.js/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v108"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/mike/Dropbox/__Documents/_Apps/_NewApps/pdf.js/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/18.4.0/bin/node /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/Users/mike/Dropbox/__Documents/_Apps/_NewApps/pdf.js/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/mike/Dropbox/__Documents/_Apps/_NewApps/pdf.js/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/mike/Dropbox/__Documents/_Apps/_NewApps/pdf.js/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:537:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.5.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/18.4.0/bin/node" "/Users/mike/Dropbox/__Documents/_Apps/_NewApps/pdf.js/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/mike/Dropbox/__Documents/_Apps/_NewApps/pdf.js/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v18.4.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.5
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mike/.npm/_logs/2022-06-29T06_21_47_463Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Did you eventually get this to work? I'm running node 9.1.1 on M2 Mac, I've got exact same error as in your first "code" section...